# matplotlib scatter fails with error: 'c' argument has n elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size n, 'y' with size n

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a scatter plot using matplotlib where each point has a specific color value.

I scale the values and then apply alpha blending between a 'left' and a 'right' color.

```
# initialization
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

values = np.random.rand(1134)

# actual code
colorLeft = np.array([112, 224, 112])
colorRight = np.array([224, 112, 112])
scaled = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(values.reshape(-1, 1))
colors = np.array([a * colorRight + (1 - a) * colorLeft for a in scaled], dtype = np.int64)
# check values here
f, [sc, other] = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sc.scatter(np.arange(len(values)), values, c = colors)
```

However the last line gives the error:

> 'c' argument has 1134 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 1134, 'y' with size 1134

The [scatter documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) says for parameter c

> c : color, sequence, or sequence of color, optional
>
> The marker color. Possible values:
>
> ```
>   A single color format string.
>   A sequence of color specifications of length n.
>   A sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm.
>   A 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA.
> ```

Where I want to use the last option with RGB values.

I replaced the `check values here` comment with some print statements:

```
print(values)
print(colors)
print(values.shape)
print(colors.shape)
```

which gave the results:

```
[0.08333333 0.08333333 0.08333333 ... 1.         1.         1.08333333]
[[112 224 112]
 [112 224 112]
 [112 224 112]
 ...
 [214 121 112]
 [214 121 112]
 [224 111 112]]
(1134,)
(1134, 3)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert colors to a float array with 0 <= colors <= 1 and it should work fine.

`sc.scatter(np.arange(len(values)), values, c = colors/255)`

Comment: If my life were a detective novel, that error message would be a red herring...

Comment: Why did you divide color by 255?