# 3D scatterplot matplotlib, adding color to plot not working?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I am creating a 3D scatter plot resulting from transforming my data using PCA (3 components). I want my data to be color coded against variable 'phi', which is an array of floats , ranging from 0-360 degrees.
variables x :[44520,3], phi[44520,1)

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument has 44520 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 44520, 'y' with size 44520.
```

Any clues?

```
signalt = dfonf.T # transpose the data as the cell #s are the features and the sampled data is the sample
pca = PCA(n_components=3)

x = pca.fit_transform(signalt)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
pcaplot = ax.scatter3D(x[:,0],x[:,1],x[:,2],c=phi,s=0.2)
cbar = fig.colorbar(pcaplot)
```

Comment: Minimal examples of `x` and `phi` ?? Please read [mre].

Comment: Try `...c=np.squeeze(phi)...`.

Comment: Doing this changed the shape of phi from (44520,1) to (44520,). I dont know why that makes a difference but it worked. Thank you for helping

Comment: how do i mark this thread as answered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib scatter fails with error: 'c' argument has n elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size n, 'y' with size n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113398/matplotlib-scatter-fails-with-error-c-argument-has-n-elements-which-is-not-a)

Comment: Possibly take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113398/matplotlib-scatter-fails-with-error-c-argument-has-n-elements-which-is-not-a

Comment: You could delete or consider [answering your own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The variable c cannot be two dimensional, converted into 1D using

`np.squeeze(phi)`

This fixed it